# Who created/invented Eloquent ORM for Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Was it Taylor Otwell himself or some company or someone else?

I am just curious and wanted to know. There is nothing to it in first page of google search so I posted the question here.

Maybe this will be down voted immediately. In that case I will delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In software engineering, the **active record pattern** is an architectural pattern found in software that stores in-memory object data in relational databases. It was named by Martin Fowler in his 2003 book Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern) The interface of an object conforming to this pattern would include functions such as Insert, Update, and Delete, plus properties that correspond more or less directly to the columns in the underlying database table.

The active record pattern is an approach to accessing data in a database. A database table or view is wrapped into a class. Thus, an object instance is tied to a single row in the table. After creation of an object, a new row is added to the table upon save. Any object loaded gets its information from the database. When an object is updated, the corresponding row in the table is also updated. The wrapper class implements accessor methods or properties for each column in the table or view.

This pattern is commonly used by object persistence tools and in object-relational **mapping (ORM)**. Typically, foreign key relationships will be exposed as an object instance of the appropriate type via a property.

Resource: Laravel Up And Running book from Matt Stauffer

then you can find it even [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern).

So Taylor only used this pattern to implement in Laravel framework even though many they consider that as a weak part of Laravel.

Comment: OK so Eloquent is just a wrapper around this active record pattern... But Taylor is the one who created it/wrapped it.